# Share folder using samba but cannot have full access other than root

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, permissions, samba

Hi I am still new using Ubuntu (16.04.02)
Please help, I created some folders to be shared using samba,
just take Public_1 dan Public_2 with the same permissions:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Jun 14 09:28 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root  4096 Jun 20 09:05 Public_1
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  4096 Jun 20 09:18 Public_2
```

and the samba setting:

```
[Public_1]
path = /media/company/Main/Public_1
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid users = @IT
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
force group = sambashare

[Public_2]
path = /media/company/Main/Public_2
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid users = @HRD @IT
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
force group = sambashare
```

This share should be able to be accessed from windows network,
the problem is using the same user but only can do edit in Public_2, in Public_1 cannot modify or create anything.

Is there any setting in ubuntu or samba that override the folder permission and samba setting?

Comment: Are you in the group IT? If not it makes totally sence that you can't

Comment: Yes, I use my user that become member of IT group. I already tried using HRD user also, but the same thing, read only.

Comment: Did you maybe change the rights in the filebrowser on windows? Did you try to restart samba? `sudo service samba reload && sudo service samba restart` how does the rest of your smb.config look like?

Comment: - No I did not change the right from windows, yes I restarted samba services everytime did the changes to smb.conf, I use the default smb.conf and add those rows [Public_1] and [Public_2]

Comment: @derHugo, i just try using sudo service samba reload && sudo service samba restart, and it comes up with error : Failed to restart samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked, before i always use sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart, are those commands different in using?

Comment: Have the files already present in the various directories unix access rights compatible with you user(s)?  I also wonder why you use `force group = sambashare`.  This means newer files created in samba will belong to the group sambashare, which is not the one your valid users are in.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen, I don't know yet how to check all unix access rights in various directories other than manually check file by file using ls -l and getfacl, and for the force group = sambashare, i use that because i want all files and folder inside will be inherited by all users belong to sambashare group (i did add my user 'yanz' and the 'hrdstaff' to sambashare group), please kindly give me your advice if i can improve the way i do the samba config...i am still learning about linux and samba.

Comment: `ls -l` is a good way to start.  Just try it within the two directories and compare the results.  You might also want to play with the ´write list` parameters, as indicated in the doc (https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html):      `This is a list of users that are given read-write access to a service. If the connecting user is in this list then they will be given write access, no matter what the read only option is set to. The list can include group names using the @group syntax.
    Example: write list = admin, root, @staff `

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen sorry i just try and reply, we were on company holiday, it still not working using write list parameter, thanks for the response